# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Registration Issue With Android 5.x.x devices

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing an android app which will support android 5.x devices. the GCM device registration work properly in all versions of android except android 5.x. Please help.

i am using below code.

```
Intent RegInt = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
RegInt.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MY_dashboard.this, 0, new Intent(), 0));

RegInt.putExtra("sender", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
startService(RegInt);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String regId = "";
regId = sharedPreferences.getString("reg", "trit:");
```

In MyReciever.js

```
if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
      regId = arg1.getStringExtra("registration_id");
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(arg0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putString("reg", regId.toString());
      editor.commit();
}
```

**Note : below error message is generated**

Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER (has extras) }

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: i have edited the question and added the error message @StillLearnin

Comment: Good! I can't help you but now it will be easier for someone else to help.

Comment: how about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this'll help. You should use the InstanceID of play services as per their documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). Register has been deprecated.

Here's my registration Code:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService{

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

    public RegistrationIntentService(){
        super("RegistrationIntentService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(Constants.SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,null);

            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            Log.v(TAG,"Token: "+token);


            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(GCMPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            //registration failed
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(GCMPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(GCMPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This is the sample provided by google for Google Cloud Messaging. Add this to your project and modify to your app:

Main Activity:

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private ProgressBar mRegistrationProgressBar;
    private TextView mInformationTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);
        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                        .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (sentToken) {
                    mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
                } else {
                    mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
                }
            }
        };
        mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

GCMListenerService:

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

InstanceIDListener: (automatically called when a new registration token is required by gcm)

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;

public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
     * InstanceID provider.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
}
```

QuickStartPreferences: (just stores constant values of keys for android cache)

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

public class QuickstartPreferences {

    public static final String SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER = "sentTokenToServer";
    public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";

}
```

Finally, the registrationIntentService:

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // [START get_token]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // [END get_token]
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]

}
```

Also, dont forget to add your configuration file to your app folder. This file is generated when you create an app from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue).

Comment: when i went to documentation you instructed to visit in your answer, it mentioned to use github and stuff, i cant understand that. @MetaSnarf

Comment: the github part contains the samples on how to use gcm. you can skip that part. Although you'd understand a lot more if you take a look at their sample. I'll post the sample here.

Comment: Thank you very much! followed all your steps but i am stuck on the point where it says you dont have google play services on phone, i am using genymotion  @MetaSnarf

Comment: Thanks It Worked! @MetaSnarf

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

Migration from Google map v2 to v3 solve the problem for me.